# Replace the URL of all my rev sliders inside images to work with new domain

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have migrated my website to a new URL and I'm wondering if there's a way to replace all the instances of the old URL with the new one using MySQL.

The images show in the Media tab but aren't linked to the slides.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you did migrate by editing Settings → General, Site URL and Wordpress URL, it might be that some plugin stored the full URL instead of the media attachment ID. In this case, you can use the WP Cli ( https://wp-cli.org/ ) to do a search-replace on the entire database. Use it like so:

```
wp search-replace 'http://old.url' 'http://new.url' --path /your/wordpress/directory/
```

on the command line of your choice (replace "wp" with the executable of your wp-cli).

Just to be on the safe side: do a backup before:

```
wp db export --add-drop-table
```

This will generate an SQL file you can use to restore your database in case anything breaks replacing the URLs.

Comment: Where should I execute this terminal line exactly?

Comment: Either, you have the `wp-cli` executable in your system's PATH. Then you can `cd` / `chdir` into the root directory of your WordPress first (--path argument is **not** necessary in this case) and run it right there, or you execute it anywhere else (correct --path to WordPress root directory **is** necessary). This command line client autmatically loads WP via wp-load.php / wp-config.php, so this works without any username or password. It just has to use your WP path as its current working directory.